# My recursive code continues to loop around 1 extra time (4 times) instead of 3 times, any solutions

Tags: python

my issue is that my subroutine goes around 1 extra time (4 times), im not sure what to do. I do not want it to go over itself 4 times i only want it to go over itself 3 times.

if tried and elif statement with the while loop and I've tried swapping the placing of the while loop with the final if statement.

```
import random

cards =['Ah','2h','3h','4h','5h','6h','7h','8h','9h','10h','Jh','Qh','Kh', 
        'Ad','2d','3d','4d','5d','6d','7d','8d','9d','10d','Jd','Qd','Kd',
        'As','2s','3s','4s','5s','6s','7s','8s','9s','10s','Js','Qs','Ks',
        'Ac','2c','3c','4c','5c','6c','7c','8c','9c','10c','Jc','Qc','Kc']

complete = random.sample(cards, 21)



def card_trick(complete, a):

    set_1 = complete[0::3]
    set_2 = complete[1::3]
    set_3 = complete[2::3]

    print ('it goes set 1, set 2, set3')
    for i in range(0,7):
        print(set_1[i],   set_2[i],    set_3[i])

    bong = int(input('enter the set your card is in 1 or 2 or 3:  '))

    if bong == 1:
        complete = set_2 + set_1 + set_3

    if bong == 2:
        complete = set_1 + set_2 + set_3

    if bong == 3:
        complete = set_1 + set_3 + set_2

    if a == 3:
        print ('your card is', complete[10])
        print ('if a == 3:, a =', a)

    while a != 3:
        a = a+1
        print ('a ================', a)
        card_trick(complete, a)

card_trick(complete, 1)
```

so the actual result is this

```
it goes set 1, set 2, set3
As 7c 9h
Qh 8c Ah
9s 10h 3c
Qs 4h 2s
Kh 7h Js
Ks 5s 3s
Jc 10s 5d
enter the set your card is in 1 or 2 or 3:  3
a ================ 2
it goes set 1, set 2, set3
As Qh 9s
Qs Kh Ks
Jc 9h Ah
3c 2s Js
3s 5d 7c
8c 10h 4h
7h 5s 10s
enter the set your card is in 1 or 2 or 3:  2
a ================ 3
it goes set 1, set 2, set3
As Qs Jc
3c 3s 8c
7h Qh Kh
9h 2s 5d
10h 5s 9s
Ks Ah Js
7c 4h 10s
enter the set your card is in 1 or 2 or 3:  1
your card is 9h
if a == 3:, a = 3
a ================ 3

#from here onwards is crap, how can i get rid of this#

it goes set 1, set 2, set3
As Qh 9s
Qs Kh Ks
Jc 9h Ah
3c 2s Js
3s 5d 7c
8c 10h 4h
7h 5s 10s
enter the set your card is in 1 or 2 or 3:  2
your card is 2s
if a == 3:, a = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your while loop to an if-statement. I've tried to make the problem visual:

```
card_trick(..., a=1)
    ...
    # a == 1
    while a != 3:
    a = 1 + 1
    # a == 2
    card_trick(..., a=2)
        ...
        #a == 2
        while a != 3:
        a = 2 + 1
        # a == 3
        card_trick(..., a=3)
            ...
            #a == 3
            while a != 3:
                # a == 3, do nothing, recursion ends, call-stack unwinds
        # a == 3, while loop of second recursion ends, go up one recursion depth
    # a == 2 on this recursion depth, so while loop goes for one more iteration
    a = 2 + 1
    # a == 3
    card_trick(..., a=3)...
```